# Error installing build on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-2.0

I am using android studio and I created an emulator(Nexus 5x). When I try to install the apk from android studio, it gives me following error

```
The currently selected variant "aosp-debug" uses split APKs, but none of the 1 split apks are compatible with the current device with density "400" and ABIs "x86".
```

Error while Installing APK

After following [THIS LINK](http://www.juce.com/forum/topic/solvedany-idea-how-solve-problem), I saw that I have correct build variant set and I am still facing this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find the answer here: [APK SPLIT](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits#TOC-ABIs-Splits)

All you need to do is to generate an x86 build. You can make this happen by following code:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk false
    }
}
```

To use emulator run command: gradlew -Px86 assemble.
This will create 2 artifacts, one for armeabi-v7a and one for x86. You can use x86 for emulator. Android studio is smart enough to choose the correct one.

Comment: in your build.gradle android{ } block. Use this link for details: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits#TOC-ABIs-Splits